# How to use set row and column delimiter in flat file connection manager editor

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I am trying to set row and column delimiters for flat file connection manager 
here the data i have The data is in .txt file

```
"Det.ID","Cus.ID","SHIP.ID","PRODUCT"----columns
"BO861"00184490"0000"09530-2"TARASCON "   ---- rows
```

For rows how to set the row delimiter  for this kind of separator

```
"BO861"00184490"0000"09530-2"TARASCON "
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find a optimal solution to read a similar file from Flat File Connection Manager, in a similar case i will do the following steps:

1. Add a Flat File Connection Manager
2. Ignore first Row
3. Uncheck reading header from first row option

[image]

4. Add 6 Columns (based on rows) manually from Advanced Tab and change columns names as wanted

[image]

5. Go to Columns Tab and change the columns delimiter to `"`

[image]

Comment: Nice Trick, This is easier than using a Script Component. +1